# Getting the id by class and then trigger click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the id by class from a dynamic div and then trigger the click function. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="navigation"> 
    <div id="nav-img1" class="slideNav"><a href="#" class="img1">img 1</a></div>
    <div id="nav-img2" class="slideNav"><a href="#" class="img2">img 2</a></div>
    <div id="nav-img3" class="slideNav"><a href="#" class="img3">img 3</a></div>
    <div id="nav-img4" class="slideNav"><a href="#" class="img4">img 4</a></div>
</div>

<div id="container-scroll">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="img1" class="slideItem">img 1</div>
        <div id="img2" class="slideItem">img 2</div>
        <div id="img3" class="slideItem">img 3</div>
        <div id="img4" class="slideItem">img 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideItem').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        var id = $('.slideNav').attr('id');
        $('.slideNav #'+id).find('a').trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope it's more clear to understand what I want to achieve by looking at the code.

Comment: your code is quite confusing, you shouldn't use IDs at all as i see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing up things a bit on the selection, try this out:

```
$('.slideItem').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.slideNav a.'+id).trigger('click');
});
```

That way you get the id of the clicked .slideItem, and trigget the click event of the .slideNav using its a class.

Answer (score 2):

You meant

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');

$('.slideNav #nav-'+id).find('a').trigger('click');
```

Comment: remove the space before `#`. It needs to be `$('.slideNav#nav-'+id)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like that, no need to use IDs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideItem').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('#navigation').find('a').get(index).click();
    });
});
```

If you want instead to trigger just jQuery handler, not DOM node click method, use:

```
 $('#navigation').find('a').eq(index).click();
```

Or:

```
$('.slideNav').eq(index).find('a').click();
```

Etc... There are many posibilities...